# How do I create or test for NaN or infinity in Perl?

Tags: perl, nan, infinity

How do I create or test for NaN or infinite values in Perl?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a fairly reliable way:

```
my $inf    = 9**9**9;
my $neginf = -9**9**9;
my $nan    = -sin(9**9**9);

sub isinf { $_[0]==9**9**9 || $_[0]==-9**9**9 }
sub isnan { ! defined( $_[0] <=> 9**9**9 ) }
# useful for detecting negative zero
sub signbit { substr( sprintf( '%g', $_[0] ), 0, 1 ) eq '-' }

for my $num ( $inf, $neginf, $nan ) {
   printf("%s:\tisinf: %d,\tisnan: %d,\tsignbit: %d\n", $num, isinf($num), isnan($num), signbit($num));
}
```

Output is:

```
inf:    isinf: 1,   isnan: 0,   signbit: 0
-inf:   isinf: 1,   isnan: 0,   signbit: 1
nan:    isinf: 0,   isnan: 1,   signbit: 0
```

Comment: On 5.10 and above, where the C library supports it, just 0+"nan", 0+"inf", or 0+"-inf" work too.

Comment: Very energetic of you: 13 minutes ago, you ask the question; 11 minutes ago, you answer it; 9 minutes ago, you post a comment. You should buy yourself a beer or something.

Comment: Interesting, where does the 9 to the 9th to the 9th power come from?  Is there a special significance or is it just an easy way to get a number big enough to blow up a variety of float specifications?

Comment: @daotoad: yes, just an easy way. Some code unfortunately used things like 100**1000, which is infinite with IEEE double precision, but not infinite with long doubles.

Comment: Just don't use this under bigint or you'll wonder why your program is hung.

Comment: Right, under bigint, use Math::BigInt->bnan(), ->binf(), or ->binf('-').

Comment: I was more concern with cases where someone turned on bigint and you didn't notice. :)

Comment: -1 because any copy/pasted solution is bad. Use the CPAN. See my answer.

Comment: @dolmen Such a fundamental check should be possible without using the CPAN. It should be a core functionality.

Answer (score 15):

```
print "Is NaN\n" if $a eq 'nan';
print "Is Inf\n" if $a eq 'inf' or $a eq '-inf';
```

**EDIT**: Fixed for negative infinity.

Comment: What if $a is not a number, but is actually the string "nan"?

Comment: @Ryan: String "nan" is not a number of course. ysth's solution works exactly same. Check `perl -le 'sub isnan { ! defined( $_[0] <=> 9**9**9 ) }; print isnan("nan")'` if you don't trust me.

Comment: Is Inf isn't quite perfect, you also want to check for '-inf'.

Comment: You need to apply the lc operator to $a before comparing, because the actual strings are things like "Inf" rather than "inf".

Comment: It seems that it changed in the last 11 years.

Comment: different platforms can differ

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would use `Math::BigFloat` (or `BigInt`) for anything that is going to touch infinity of `NaN`.

Why reinvent the wheel with a hack solution when there are already modules that do the job?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Data::Float](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aFloat) from CPAN. It exports the following functions:

- `float_is_infinite(`)
- `float_is_nan()`
- ...

And contrary to the others half-working solutions posted here, it has a [testsuite](https://metacpan.org/source/ZEFRAM/Data-Float-0.012/t/class.t).

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Data::Float`s check for `NaN` is dependent on `NaN` support on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

When I searched I got this site (here) and http://www.learning-perl.com/2015/05/perls-special-not-a-numbers/

The linked article points out that "nan" == "nan" is never true, when the underlying c implementation supports NaN because Nan cannot match itself.

This is nicely illustrated with

```
die "This perl does not support NaN!\n" if "NaN" == "NaN";
```

I guess the risk of running you code in an environment where perl has degraded gracefully and your code has not might be low enough so that you don't worry too much.

And of course if you don't want perl to interpolate as a number, use 'eq' not '=='

Answer (score 0):

```perl
sub is_nan($) { $_[0] != $_[0] }
sub is_inf($) { scalar $_[0] =~ /^-?inf$/ }
```

NaN is `NaN` on input (but not on output; there it's `nan` (for whatever reason)).
And Perl understands `inf` and `-inf`:

```perl-db
  DB<31> x is_nan 7
0  ''
  DB<32> x is_nan NaN
0  1
  DB<33> x is_nan 'NaN'
0  1
  DB<34> x is_nan inf
0  ''
  DB<38> x is_inf 4
0  ''
  DB<39> x is_inf inf
0  1
  DB<40> x is_inf -inf
0  1
  DB<41> x is_inf '-inf'
0  1
  DB<42> x is_nan 'NaN' + 3
0  1
  DB<43> x is_nan 'NaN' + inf
0  1
  DB<44> x is_nan inf
0  ''
  DB<45> x is_nan inf - inf
0  1
  DB<46> x is_nan -inf + inf
0  1
  DB<47> x inf > 0
0  1
  DB<48> x inf < 0
0  ''
  DB<49> x -inf > 0
0  ''
  DB<50> x -inf < 0
0  1
```

Comment: pretty sure some platforms have INF or Inf, not inf.  why the $ anchor but no starting ^ anchor?

Comment: On missing `^` : I'm forced to use Windows, where some keys are "dead keys", so sometimes they are swallowed, even if I had typed them -- corrected, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score -2):

Succinct answer that works follows.

1: How to create a "NAN" variable for output (to printf, for example):

```
 {no strict 'subs'; $NAN="NAN"+1;}
```

2: How to test for "NAN" (looks like ascii art):

```
 sub isnan {!($_[0]<=0||$_[0]>=0)}
```

3: How to create an "INF" and INFN variables:

```
{$INF="INF"+1; $INFN=-"INF"+1}
```

4: How to test for "INF" (of any sign):

```
sub isinf {($_[0]==+"INF")||($_[0]==-"INF")}
```

Comment: (1) and (3) are no different than just `$NAN = "NAN"+1;`, `$INF = "INF"+1; $INFN = -"INF";` just more verbose

Comment: oh, I see (4) uses barewords too, only without disabling strict.  And all of these that rely on strings like "NAN" and "INF" becoming the appropriate "number" in numeric context will fail on older perls or where the C runtime doesn't support it (e.g. strawberry perl or activeperl on windows)

Comment: A _comprehensive_ answer would include a testsuite.

Comment: Changed it to be more clear... it's a succinct, correct answer.  Also works on activeperl/windows, etc.

Comment: You don't need the `no strict 'subs'` anymore if you don't use barewords. So your solution (still without testsuite) could be more succint. And `isinf` is still not efficient.

Comment: i removed all the barewords