# How do I check scalar for an 'inf' value in Perl?

Tags: perl, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create or test for NaN or infinity in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185822/how-do-i-create-or-test-for-nan-or-infinity-in-perl)

How can I check, if scalar holds `inf` value?

I check NaN as `$scalar != $scalar`, what to do with `inf`?

`$scalar == inf` does not work, since `inf` is a bareword

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185822/how-do-i-create-or-test-for-nan-or-infinity-in-perl

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check for infinity:

```
$scalar < 9**9**9
```

that constant is so large that it will be interpreted as infinite by Perl

Answer (score -1):

I found a dirty hack right now.

```
($scalar eq "inf")
```

Does anything cleaner exist?

Comment: Not good.  Perl will stringify inf however the underlying libc does, and that can vary (both within the C standard and, on Windows, far outside it).