# Strange behaviour of sort

Tags: perl, sorting

I have this piece of script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = (
    {
        name  => 'foo',
        value => 123,
    },
    {
        name  => 'bar',
        value => 'nan',
    },
    {
        name  => 'foobar',
        value => 456,
    },
);

@arr = sort {$a->{value} <=> $b->{value} } @arr;

print Dumper(\@arr);
```

I don't have any problems under Windows XP / Strawberry Perl 5.10.1

either Linux 2.6.12-1 i386 / Perl v5.8.5 built for i386-linux-thread-multi,

but under Linux  2.6.18-53 / Perl v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi, i got the error message :

```
Sort subroutine didn't return a numeric value at testsort.pl line 21.
```

What's going wrong and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you simplify it like this?
    @arr = sort { $a <=> $b } (123, 'nan', 456);

Comment: @wdebeaum: no errors in one liner but doesn't sort anything under x86_64 whilst it's ok under win XP and i386

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some builds, 'nan' is coerced to the number 0 for a `<=>` comparison and the sort succeeds. In other builds, `nan` is treated as "not a number" and the return value from `<=>` is undefined.

For maximum portability, test a value for whether it is a good number of not:

(`isnan` subroutine from [How do I create or test for NaN or infinity in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185822/how-do-i-create-or-test-for-nan-or-infinity-in-perl)):

```
sub isnan { ! defined( $_[0] <=> 9**9**9 ) }

@arr = sort { isnan($a->{value}) ? 0 : $a->{value}
                         <=>  
              isnan($b->{value}) ? 0 : $b->{value} }  @arr;
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2 Solutions

1. **[mobrule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mobrule)'s solution:**

   ```
   sub isnan { ! defined( $_[0] <=> 9**9**9 ) }
   @arr = sort { isnan($a->{value}) ? 0 : $a->{value}
                                 <=>  
                 isnan($b->{value}) ? 0 : $b->{value} }  @arr;
   ```
2. **[Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)'s solution:**

   ```
   @result = sort { $a <=> $b } grep { $_ == $_ } @input;
   ```

---

1. Gives your `NaN` a `0` value, which should push it to the top of the list.
2. Takes advantage that `NaN != NaN`, to eliminate any `NaN`s from the input list.

---

As [mobrule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mobrule) stated, this is caused by the comparison of `NaN` between builds.